# converting string and int to bytes32 and vice versa doesn't return same value

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, dapps, erc-721

I am trying to send a set of values, which contain 3 strings and 1 integer, as a bytes32 array to a function. The original values that I want to convert to bytes32 were
`["maham",67,"Silven","first token", "image url"]`
. I convert these to a 66 hexadecimal string and passed the following array instead

```
["0x6d6168616d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x4300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x53696c7665720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x666972737420746f6b656e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x696d6167652075726c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
```

Now I want to convert these hexadecimal strings back to string and my code is as follows:

```
function drawCard(string memory _tokenURI, bytes32[] memory params) public {
        uint _check  = uint(params[1]);
        entered_supply = _check;
        require(_check<total_supply,
        "Input supply is not less than total supply of cards.");
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newNftTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
        
        Cards memory c;
        c.name = string(abi.encodePacked(params[0]));
        check_name = c.name;
        c.supply = _check;
        c.cat = string(abi.encodePacked(params[2]));
        c.description = string(abi.encodePacked(params[3]));
        c.image_url= string(abi.encodePacked(params[4]));
        c.card_id = newNftTokenId;
```

however remix shows the following values after conversion back to string

[image]

Please tell me how can I convert the hexadecimal strings back to original strings and integer value.